# How downloading binary files from DataSnap?

Tags: c++builder, datasnap, c++builder-10.1-berlin

I am using RAD Studio 10.1 Berlin.  I am trying to create a server method in DataSnap to serve binary files:

```cpp
FileStream* TServerMethods::acceptExportReport(const String& fileName)   
{ 
    TStream* stream  = new TFileStream(outPath, fmOpenRead | fmShareDenyNone);
    stream->Position = 0;
    GetInvocationMetadata()->ResponseContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    return stream;
}
```

When I open it from web browser, I get json content, not binary data.  Something like:

```json
  {"result":[[45,45,45,45,45...
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you encode it base64 ?. AFAIK if your Datasnap is a REST server you will always get a JSON.

Comment: "application/octet-stream" is not, in general, viewable in most browsers. What are you trying to download? For a png image, for instance, you should use "image/png" instead.

Comment: Thanks Marc. It put me in the correct track. Now I am using 'actions', in WebModule, to serve file content and now it works fine. I was not aware that PersistentClass (ServerMethods) returns always json. I thought it returned the function return type. In fact, there are some examples in the web, so I am not totally clear, but at least, now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put ?json=false at the end of the url